# Что нужно сделать, чтобы прямоугольная область фигуры, появлялась только после нажатия на фигуру?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyside2, qgraphicsview

Что нужно сделать, чтобы прямоугольная область фигуры, появлялась только после нажатия на фигуру? 
Чтобы желтые точки появлялись только при нажатии на фигуру.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Исходный код:

```
 import sys
    import random
    from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRectF, QPointF, QTimer
    from PyQt5.QtGui import QBrush, QPainterPath, QPainter, QColor, QPen, QPixmap
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QGraphicsRectItem, QApplication, QGraphicsView,
                                 QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsItem)
    
    
    class GraphicsRectItem(QGraphicsRectItem):
        handleTopLeft = 1
        handleTopMiddle = 2
        handleTopRight = 3
        handleMiddleLeft = 4
        handleMiddleRight = 5
        handleBottomLeft = 6
        handleBottomMiddle = 7
        handleBottomRight = 8
    
        handleSize = +8.0
        handleSpace = -4.0
    
        handleCursors = {
            handleTopLeft: Qt.SizeFDiagCursor,
            handleTopMiddle: Qt.SizeVerCursor,
            handleTopRight: Qt.SizeBDiagCursor,
            handleMiddleLeft: Qt.SizeHorCursor,
            handleMiddleRight: Qt.SizeHorCursor,
            handleBottomLeft: Qt.SizeBDiagCursor,
            handleBottomMiddle: Qt.SizeVerCursor,
            handleBottomRight: Qt.SizeFDiagCursor,
        }
    
        def __init__(self, *args):
            super().__init__(*args)
            self.handles = {}
            self.handleSelected = None
            self.mousePressPos = None
            self.mousePressRect = None
            self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)
            self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
            self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
            self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges, True)
            self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable, True)
            self.updateHandlesPos()
    
        def handleAt(self, point):
            """  Возвращает маркер изменения размера ниже заданной точки.
            """
            for k, v, in self.handles.items():
                if v.contains(point):
                    return k
            return None
    
        def hoverMoveEvent(self, moveEvent):
            if self.isSelected():
                handle = self.handleAt(moveEvent.pos())
                cursor = Qt.ArrowCursor if handle is None else self.handleCursors[handle]
                self.setCursor(cursor)
    
            super().hoverMoveEvent(moveEvent)
    
    
        def hoverLeaveEvent(self, moveEvent):
            self.setCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)
    
            super().hoverLeaveEvent(moveEvent)
    
        def mousePressEvent(self, mouseEvent):
            """ Выполняется при нажатии мыши на item.
            """
            self.handleSelected = self.handleAt(mouseEvent.pos())
            if self.handleSelected:
                self.mousePressPos = mouseEvent.pos()
                self.mousePressRect = self.boundingRect()
    
            super().mousePressEvent(mouseEvent)
    
        def mouseMoveEvent(self, mouseEvent):
            """ Выполняется, когда мышь перемещается по элементу при нажатии.
            """
    
            if self.handleSelected is not None:
                self.interactiveResize(mouseEvent.pos())
            else:
                super().mouseMoveEvent(mouseEvent)
    
        def mouseReleaseEvent(self, mouseEvent):
            """ Выполняется, когда мышь is released from the item.
            """
    
            super().mouseReleaseEvent(mouseEvent)
            self.handleSelected = None
            self.mousePressPos = None
            self.mousePressRect = None
            self.update()
    
        def boundingRect(self):
            """ Возвращает ограничивающий прямоугольник фигуры
            (включая маркеры изменения размера).
            """
            o = self.handleSize + self.handleSpace
            return self.rect().adjusted(-o, -o, o, o)
    
        def updateHandlesPos(self):
            """ Обновите текущие маркеры изменения размера
            в соответствии с размером и положением фигуры.
            """
            s = self.handleSize
            b = self.boundingRect()
            self.handles[self.handleTopLeft] = QRectF(b.left(), b.top(), s, s)
            self.handles[self.handleTopMiddle] = QRectF(b.center().x() - s / 2, b.top(), s, s)
            self.handles[self.handleTopRight] = QRectF(b.right() - s, b.top(), s, s)
            self.handles[self.handleMiddleLeft] = QRectF(b.left(), b.center().y() - s / 2, s, s)
            self.handles[self.handleMiddleRight] = QRectF(b.right() - s, b.center().y() - s / 2, s, s)
            self.handles[self.handleBottomLeft] = QRectF(b.left(), b.bottom() - s, s, s)
            self.handles[self.handleBottomMiddle] = QRectF(b.center().x() - s / 2, b.bottom() - s, s, s)
            self.handles[self.handleBottomRight] = QRectF(b.right() - s, b.bottom() - s, s, s)
    
        def interactiveResize(self, mousePos):
            """ Выполните интерактивное изменение размера формы.
            """
            offset = self.handleSize + self.handleSpace
            boundingRect = self.boundingRect()
            rect = self.rect()
            diff = QPointF(0, 0)
    
            self.prepareGeometryChange()
    
            if self.handleSelected == self.handleTopLeft:
                fromX = self.mousePressRect.left()
                fromY = self.mousePressRect.top()
                toX = fromX + mousePos.x() - self.mousePressPos.x()
                toY = fromY + mousePos.y() - self.mousePressPos.y()
                diff.setX(toX - fromX)
                diff.setY(toY - fromY)
                boundingRect.setLeft(toX)
                boundingRect.setTop(toY)
                rect.setLeft(boundingRect.left() + offset)
                rect.setTop(boundingRect.top() + offset)
                self.setRect(rect)
            elif self.handleSelected == self.handleTopMiddle:
                fromY = self.mousePressRect.top()
                toY = fromY + mousePos.y() - self.mousePressPos.y()
                diff.setY(toY - fromY)
                boundingRect.setTop(toY)
                rect.setTop(boundingRect.top() + offset)
                self.setRect(rect)
            elif self.handleSelected == self.handleTopRight:
                fromX = self.mousePressRect.right()
                fromY = self.mousePressRect.top()
                toX = fromX + mousePos.x() - self.mousePressPos.x()
                toY = fromY + mousePos.y() - self.mousePressPos.y()
                diff.setX(toX - fromX)
                diff.setY(toY - fromY)
                boundingRect.setRight(toX)
                boundingRect.setTop(toY)
                rect.setRight(boundingRect.right() - offset)
                rect.setTop(boundingRect.top() + offset)
                self.setRect(rect)
            elif self.handleSelected == self.handleMiddleLeft:
                fromX = self.mousePressRect.left()
                toX = fromX + mousePos.x() - self.mousePressPos.x()
                diff.setX(toX - fromX)
                boundingRect.setLeft(toX)
                rect.setLeft(boundingRect.left() + offset)
                self.setRect(rect)
            elif self.handleSelected == self.handleMiddleRight:
                fromX = self.mousePressRect.right()
                toX = fromX + mousePos.x() - self.mousePressPos.x()
                diff.setX(toX - fromX)
                boundingRect.setRight(toX)
                rect.setRight(boundingRect.right() - offset)
                self.setRect(rect)
            elif self.handleSelected == self.handleBottomLeft:
                fromX = self.mousePressRect.left()
                fromY = self.mousePressRect.bottom()
                toX = fromX + mousePos.x() - self.mousePressPos.x()
                toY = fromY + mousePos.y() - self.mousePressPos.y()
                diff.setX(toX - fromX)
                diff.setY(toY - fromY)
                boundingRect.setLeft(toX)
                boundingRect.setBottom(toY)
                rect.setLeft(boundingRect.left() + offset)
                rect.setBottom(boundingRect.bottom() - offset)
                self.setRect(rect)
            elif self.handleSelected == self.handleBottomMiddle:
                fromY = self.mousePressRect.bottom()
                toY = fromY + mousePos.y() - self.mousePressPos.y()
                diff.setY(toY - fromY)
                boundingRect.setBottom(toY)
                rect.setBottom(boundingRect.bottom() - offset)
                self.setRect(rect)
            elif self.handleSelected == self.handleBottomRight:
                fromX = self.mousePressRect.right()
                fromY = self.mousePressRect.bottom()
                toX = fromX + mousePos.x() - self.mousePressPos.x()
                toY = fromY + mousePos.y() - self.mousePressPos.y()
                diff.setX(toX - fromX)
                diff.setY(toY - fromY)
                boundingRect.setRight(toX)
                boundingRect.setBottom(toY)
                rect.setRight(boundingRect.right() - offset)
                rect.setBottom(boundingRect.bottom() - offset)
                self.setRect(rect)
    
            self.updateHandlesPos()
    
        def shape(self):
            """ Возвращает форму этого элемента в виде QPainterPath в локальных координатах.
            """
            path = QPainterPath()
            path.addRect(self.rect())
            if self.isSelected():
                for shape in self.handles.values():
                    path.addEllipse(shape)
            return path
    
        def paint(self, painter, option, widget=None):
            """ Нарисуйте узел в графическом представлении.
            """
            painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(255, 0, 0, 100)))
            painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(0, 0, 0), 1.0, Qt.SolidLine))
            painter.drawRect(self.rect())
            painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
            painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(255, 255, 0, 255)))  # маркеры
            painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(0, 0, 0, 255), 1.0, Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin))
            for handle, rect in self.handles.items():
                if self.handleSelected is None or handle == self.handleSelected:
                    painter.drawEllipse(rect)
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    
        grview = QGraphicsView()
        scene = QGraphicsScene(grview)
        scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 680, 459)
        grview.setScene(scene)
    
        for _ in range(10):
            item = GraphicsRectItem(*random.sample(range(100), 4))
            scene.addItem(item)
    
    
        grview.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Все прямоугольники выделены, а должен быть выделен тот, на который мы нажали для масштабирования:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

я не совсем понял ваш вопрос, но приведу пример о чем я подумал. Пожалуйста ВСЕГДА предоставляйте минимально-воспроизводимый пример!

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore


class GripItem(QtWidgets.QGraphicsPathItem):
    circle = QtGui.QPainterPath()
    circle.addEllipse(QtCore.QRectF(-5, -5, 10, 10))
    square = QtGui.QPainterPath()
    square.addRect(QtCore.QRectF(-10, -10, 20, 20))

    def __init__(self, annotation_item, index):
        super(GripItem, self).__init__()
        self.m_annotation_item = annotation_item
        self.m_index = index

        self.setPath(GripItem.circle)
        self.setBrush(QtGui.QColor("green"))
        self.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor("green"), 2))
        self.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
        self.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
        self.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges, True)
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)
        self.setZValue(11)
        self.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))

    def hoverEnterEvent(self, event):
        self.setPath(GripItem.square)
        self.setBrush(QtGui.QColor("red"))
        super(GripItem, self).hoverEnterEvent(event)

    def hoverLeaveEvent(self, event):
        self.setPath(GripItem.circle)
        self.setBrush(QtGui.QColor("green"))
        super(GripItem, self).hoverLeaveEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.setSelected(False)
        super(GripItem, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)

    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        if change == QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemPositionChange and self.isEnabled():
            self.m_annotation_item.movePoint(self.m_index, value)
        return super(GripItem, self).itemChange(change, value)


class DirectionGripItem(GripItem):
    def __init__(self, annotation_item, direction=QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, parent=None):
        super(DirectionGripItem, self).__init__(annotation_item, parent)
        self._direction = direction

    @property
    def direction(self):
        return self._direction

    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        if change == QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemPositionChange and self.isEnabled():
            p = QtCore.QPointF(self.pos())
            if self.direction == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
                p.setX(value.x())
            elif self.direction == QtCore.Qt.Vertical:
                p.setY(value.y())
            self.m_annotation_item.movePoint(self.m_index, p)
            return p
        return super(DirectionGripItem, self).itemChange(change, value)


class CircleAnnotation(QtWidgets.QGraphicsEllipseItem):
    def __init__(self, radius=1, parent=None):
        super(CircleAnnotation, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setZValue(11)
        self.m_items = []

        self.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor("green"), 4))

        self.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
        self.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
        self.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges, True)

        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)

        self.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))

        self._radius = radius
        self.update_rect()

    @property
    def radius(self):
        return self._radius

    @radius.setter
    def radius(self, r):
        if r <= 0:
            raise ValueError("радиус должен быть положительным")
        self._radius = r
        self.update_rect()
        self.add_grip_items()
        self.update_items_positions()

    def update_rect(self):
        rect = QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 2 * self.radius, 2 * self.radius)
        rect.moveCenter(self.rect().center())
        self.setRect(rect)

    def add_grip_items(self):
        if self.scene() and not self.m_items:
            for i, (direction) in enumerate(
                (
                    QtCore.Qt.Vertical,
                    QtCore.Qt.Horizontal,
                    QtCore.Qt.Vertical,
                    QtCore.Qt.Horizontal,
                )
            ):
                item = DirectionGripItem(self, direction, i)
                self.scene().addItem(item)
                self.m_items.append(item)

    def movePoint(self, i, p):
        if 0 <= i < min(4, len(self.m_items)):
            item_selected = self.m_items[i]
            lp = self.mapFromScene(p)
            self._radius = (lp - self.rect().center()).manhattanLength()
            k = self.indexOf(lp)
            if k is not None:
                self.m_items = [item for item in self.m_items if not item.isSelected()]
                self.m_items.insert(k, item_selected)
                self.update_items_positions([k])
                self.update_rect()

    def update_items_positions(self, index_no_updates=None):
        index_no_updates = index_no_updates or []
        for i, (item, direction) in enumerate(
            zip(
                self.m_items,
                (
                    QtCore.Qt.Vertical,
                    QtCore.Qt.Horizontal,
                    QtCore.Qt.Vertical,
                    QtCore.Qt.Horizontal,
                ),
            ),
        ):
            item.m_index = i
            if i not in index_no_updates:
                pos = self.mapToScene(self.point(i))
                item = self.m_items[i]
                item._direction = direction
                item.setEnabled(False)
                item.setPos(pos)
                item.setEnabled(True)

    def indexOf(self, p):
        for i in range(4):
            if p == self.point(i):
                return i

    def point(self, index):
        if 0 <= index < 4:
            return [
                QtCore.QPointF(0, -self.radius),
                QtCore.QPointF(self.radius, 0),
                QtCore.QPointF(0, self.radius),
                QtCore.QPointF(-self.radius, 0),
            ][index]

    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        if change == QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemPositionHasChanged:
            self.update_items_positions()
            return
        if change == QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemSceneHasChanged:
            self.add_grip_items()
            self.update_items_positions()
            return
        return super(CircleAnnotation, self).itemChange(change, value)

    def hoverEnterEvent(self, event):
        self.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0, 100))
        super(CircleAnnotation, self).hoverEnterEvent(event)

    def hoverLeaveEvent(self, event):
        self.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.NoBrush))
        super(CircleAnnotation, self).hoverLeaveEvent(event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
    view = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(scene)
    view.setRenderHints(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
    item = CircleAnnotation()
    item.radius = 100
    scene.addItem(item)
    view.showMaximized()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Прикольно вышло, но не то что я хотел. Я хотел, чтобы прямоугольная область появлялась только после нажатия на фигуру.

Comment: @pythmy ну так нажмите на фигуру и вы получите что хотите

Comment: Точки масштабирования не пропадают

Comment: добавил скриншоты, переформулировал немного

Comment: @pythmy   пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve] , который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: все увидел, работает, спасибо большое)) извините за то что тупил